# Launch ColorBox (containing JQuery Accordion) - from client-side code

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, colorbox, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a JQuery Accordion that is inside of a Colorbox.  I am able to launch the Accordion/Colorbox from a simple link (using an HTML anchor tag with the accordion elements' id specified as the "href").

However, I need to delay this and 1st call a server side handler with JQuery/AJAX (from a button click).  I need to then launch the JQuery Accordion/Colorbox.

There should be some way to fire the Accordion/Colorbox from a JQuery function.  The technique that I'm using to launch this from the anchor tag is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GLWB6/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: 'content',
                collapsible: true,                    
                active: 0,                    
                activate: function (event, ui) {
                    $.colorbox.resize();
                }
            });                
        });

        $(".inline").colorbox({
            inline: true,
            innerWidth: '400px',
            innerHeight: '400px',
            scrolling: false,

        });
    });
```

```
<p><a class='inline' href="#accordion">Launch Accordion/Colorbox</a></p>
<div style="display:none">
<div id="accordion">
     <h3>Step 2: Enter your information</h3>

    <div>
        <p>The input fields will go here</p>
    </div>

     <h3>Step 3: Thank you!</h3>

    <div>
        <p>The confirmation message, with the localize business information will go here</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Title</li>
            <li>Address/Phone</li>
            <li>Link to Web Site</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</div>
```

The Goal is to launch the colorbox/accordion **after** the server-side handler is called via the JQuery/AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({

                type: "Post",
                url: "/handlers/getCustomData.ashx",
                data: {
                    custID: custID.value
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    //Launch colorbox/accordion, here }
       })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/5A3Pu/

```
<a id="accordionBTN" class='inline' href="#accordion">Inline HTML</a>
$('#accordionBTN').trigger('click');
```

EDIT: The final version of the jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/5A3Pu/3/

Comment: No, I don't think so.  The goal is to return to the browser (after the handler is called), and in the JQuery AJAX "success" function - launch the colorbox/accordion.

Comment: After "success" couldn't you just call `$('#accordionBTN').trigger('click');` ... or am I missing something?

Comment: No, but that's an interesting approach.  The anchor tag is just something that I found that's at least launching the colorbox/accordion.  I tried the trigger('click') method, but that's not really working - the colorbox "flickers", briefly for a millesecond.

Comment: So how about this then? http://jsfiddle.net/5A3Pu/1/ then after `success` you can call the function `openColorBox`

Comment: I'm not sure if the function call is working, or not.  It's loading the colorbox every time the page loads or a post-back is triggered.  I'd like to just call that function to launch it, but only after the handler is called.  And keep the colorbox/accordion hidden, until the right moment.

Comment: Did you try calling the function like I'm showing it on this version. http://jsfiddle.net/5A3Pu/3/ ... on this version I have incorporated your `$.ajax` to show you exactly where I'm thinking the function call should go.